# Azure-provided name resolution for load balancer

Tags: azure, load-balancing, azure-virtual-machine, internal-load-balancer

When we launch a VM or create a NIC within the Azure VNET, by default, it been assign the internal DNS, something of pattern (*.internal.cloudapp.net)

As it's mention in this document
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/virtual-machines-linux-azure-dns#azure-provided-name-resolution

> When using Azure-provided name resolution, an Internal DNS suffix
>   (*.internal.cloudapp.net) is provided to each VM using DHCP.

How do I get the same for internal load balancer? I am using Azure ARM based load balancer not the cloud service one.
I can assign static private IP, but it won't get resolve to internal DNS like VM does

Answer (score 0):

In Azure, the Azure-provided name resolution service is provided between VMs in virtual networks,so we can't get the internal DNS for the internal load balancer.

Comment: OP is using an internal load balancer, surely it doesn't have a public IP address as in the image?

Comment: If OP has 2 VMs behind the internal load balancer, then in your way you would get 2 FQDNs and could just delete the internal load balancer right? OP is asking how to assign an FQDN to the load balancer, not the VMs directly.

Comment: @JasonYe-MSFT: If you associate Public IP to internal load balancer, you are exposing your load balancer to internet. Another point, using public FQDN, your internal traffic now needs to route to internet to get to the load balancer. Wouldn't it be convenient, if there is some way that load balancer gets internal DNS like NIC's and VM gets when in a VNET.

Comment: @juunas Thank you for your suggestion, you are right

Comment: @Shabbir you are right, we can't associate Public IP to internal load balancer. The Internal load balancer used for internal communication, so in the same Vnet, we can use private IP address. In Azure, the Azure-provided name resolution service is provided between VMs in virtual networks,so we can't get the internal DNS for the internal load balancer.